# jailbreakqa.com have copied stackexchange

Tags: support, stack-overflow, copyright, copycat-sites, copyright-infringement

[jailbreaqa.com](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/) have copied the stackexchange (especially stackoverflow).

some screenshots of the site:

[image]

and also this one:

[image]

[Note: Whether we can report this kind stuff here or not, I don't know. I am just trying to catch the eye of this site owners as it can mislead original users of this site.]

Comment: lol, almost all closed :D for being solved :D

Comment: It's neither the first nor the last to copy Stack Overflow model, there are hundreds of those. Some legal and some are not, but all should be reported in the linked dupe.

Comment: "Powered by OSQA." - It's a known clone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why don't you take action against them?

Comment: @krupal I'm just an ordinary person. If you mean Stack Exchange company then I assume they do act against the illegal clones (those who copy exact design) in whatever ways the law lets them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok...I understand this.